# Как представить модель для движений по счёту, где количество транзакции огромное число?

Tags: c#, архитектура, проектирование

```
/// интерфейс счёта
public interface IPersonalAccount
{
    Person Owner { get; }
    string Account { get; }
}
```

Как представить модель для движений по счёту, где количество транзакции огромное число?

Comment: Так же как и в том случае где количество транзакций составляет несколько чисел. В чём конкретно вопрос?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если говорить об интерфейсе. То разделять их это верная стратегия.

```
/// интерфейс счёта
public interface IPersonalAccount
{
    IPerson Person { get; }
    IAccount Account { get; }
}

public interface ITransaction{
  IPersonalAccount Debitor { get;}
  IPersonalAccount Creditor { get;}
  ICurrency Currency { get;}
  Decimal Amount {get;}
  DateTimeOffset Date {get;}
}

IList<ITransaction> transactions = ....
```

Comment: Данных на самом деле много в интерфейс выделить все основные для работы. можно добавить статусы и прочее.

Comment: Хорошо! PS: думаю, вместо DateTime правильнее будет использовать DateTimeOffset. https://stackoverflow.com/a/14268167/5045688

Comment: @Aziz Umarov А если использовать перечисление
public interface **ITransactions** ?

Comment: Не понятно чем вы хотите расширить IList. И в целом конечно задавайте отдельно вопросы